# How to display estimatedProgress of WKWebView in a Linear style ProgressView in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I tried searching for weeks on this matter and I can't find any help that is implemented in SwiftUI. Most of the answers were for UIKit.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var progress: Double = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            WebView()

            ProgressView(value: progress)
                .progressViewStyle(.linear)
        }
    }
}

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!))
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are using `UIViewRepresentable` to wrap `WKWebView` you need to use a `UIKit` solution.

We can track the **estimatedProgress** of the `WKWebView` using Key-Value-Observing (KVO). For this we need to add a Coordinator to our `WebView`.

Just adding the coordinator is not enough we need a way to pass the value back from the `UIViewRepresentable` to the `View`. We could do this using a `@Binding` or a closure, but this will cause the following error when the view is updated:

> Warning: Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.

A "hacky" solution is to wrap the setting of the bound `progress` variable using `DispatchQueue.main.async` but this is not a good solution.

A better way to get around this problem is to create a simple ViewModel that conforms to `ObservableObject`.

This gives the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = WebView.ProgressViewModel(progress: 0.0)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            WebView(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!, viewModel: viewModel)

            ProgressView(value: viewModel.progress)
                .progressViewStyle(.linear)
        }
    }
}
```

The `ContentView` now holds a reference to the `ProgressViewModel` this is passed, along with the URL, to the `WebView`. The `ProgressView` is passed the `@Published` progress from the `ProgressViewModel`.

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let url: URL
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ProgressViewModel

    private let webView = WKWebView()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

There isn't much difference between this and your `UIViewRepresentable` except that we are passing the the `URL` and the `ProgressViewModel`. We have also raised the initialisation of the webView out of the `makeUIView`, this is so that we can have access to it in the `Coordinator`.

```
extension WebView {

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, viewModel: viewModel)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        private var parent: WebView
        private var viewModel: ProgressViewModel
        private var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?

        init(_ parent: WebView, viewModel: ProgressViewModel) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.viewModel = viewModel
            super.init()

            observer = self.parent.webView.observe(\.estimatedProgress) { [weak self] webView, _ in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.parent.viewModel.progress = webView.estimatedProgress
            }
        }

        deinit {
            observer = nil
        }
    }
}
```

This extension on `WebView` creates the coordinator, which inherits from `NSObject`. It holds references to the parent, the `WebView`, and the viewModel. We set up a KVO observer in the initializer observing the `estimatedProgress` on the webView, this allows us to update the progress value on our viewModel.

```
extension WebView {
    class ProgressViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var progress: Double = 0.0

        init (progress: Double) {
            self.progress = progress
        }
    }
}
```

Finally this is the `ProgressViewModel` that ties the `UIViewRepresentable` and the `View` together.

You can see a video of it [here](https://i.imgur.com/tiSislP.mp4)

Comment: Thanks alot for the damn useful reply. My only question is the purpose of [weak self] and this particular line of code "guard let self = self else { return }". Like why did the Coordinator become an optional? Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: You should weakify `self` when using it inside a closure otherwise you run the risk of  retain cycles. When you use `[weak self]` it makes `self` optional, hence the need to unwrap it.  But in this case you could ignore the `guard let self = self else { return }` and use `self?.parent.viewModel.progress = webView.estimatedProgress` instead (notice the `?` after the self).